# Validate the input text data against the data list on key up

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to re-use this `ValidateInput()` function because I have more such input with the datalist in my code.

Below is the code.

```
<input id="input-id" list="datalist-id" type="text" placeholder="Select Cluster Group" ng-keyup="ValidateInput()" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="datalist-id">
    <div ng-repeat="country in Countries">
        <option> {{country.name}} </option>
    </div>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirement**

1. If there are so many `datalist` each associated with `input` tag.
2. Then you can get the `id`of `datalist` from the `id` of the `input` tag by passing the `id` of the `input` tag in to the `ValidateInput('#input-id')` on `ng-keyup` event.
3. After that you can `validate` the data provided in the `input` text against the `datalist`.

**Code**

```js
//Method to valdate the input against the datalist items.
var myApp = angular.module("my-app", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {
$scope.Countries = [{name: "Nepal"}, {name: "India"}, {name: "China"}, {name: "Pakistan"}];

$scope.ValidateInput = function (InputId) {
 var listId = '#' + $(InputId).attr('list');

 $(InputId).removeAttr('style');

 $(listId).each(function () {
  if (!$(InputId).val() || !$(this).text().toLowerCase().includes($(InputId).val().toLowerCase())) {
   $(InputId).css('border', '3px solid red');
   return false;
  }
 });
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="myController">
<input id="input-id" list="datalist-id" type="text" placeholder="Select Country" ng-keyup="ValidateInput('#input-id')" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="datalist-id">
    <div ng-repeat="country in Countries">
        <option> {{country.name}} </option>
    </div>
</datalist>
</div>
```